# Prometheus metrics vs micrometer metrics (Spring 2)

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, metrics

I am using prometheus to monitor some out of the box and some custom application metrics.
For custom metrics, i am not using the Prometheus client library, i am using the `io.micrometer` packages for custom Counters and Gauges.

The custom metrics i create are still visible in the prometheus endpoint `(http://localhost:9090/actuator/prometheus)`. In that case, why do we even need a Prometheus client library? Should i be using one over the other or a mix of both of them? They seem to be using different types of registries which makes it impossible to combine them.

Comment: Have you found anything by now?

Answer (score 11):

Old question, not sure if you have found answer yet. But here's my take:

Micrometer is lets your code be agnostic to the monitoring hosting solution you use.  You could code your metrics in a single solution that could publish it to Prometheus or Azure monitor or Influx or etc. In your case you are using Prometheus as your monitoring solution, hence you might as well use Prometheus client. But in the future if you wanted to switch to another monitoring solution, instrumenting your code with Micrometer would make the switch easier.

From the micrometer website:

"As an instrumentation facade, Micrometer allows you to instrument your code with dimensional metrics with a vendor-neutral interface and decide on the monitoring system as a last step. Instrumenting your core library code with Micrometer allows the libraries to be included in applications that ship metrics to different backends.

Contains built-in support for AppOptics, Azure Monitor, Netflix Atlas, CloudWatch, Datadog, Dynatrace, Elastic, Ganglia, Graphite, Humio, Influx/Telegraf, JMX, KairosDB, New Relic, Prometheus, SignalFx, Google Stackdriver, StatsD, and Wavefront."

Comment: Would it be correct to say that Micrometer is a specification and the Prometheus client or Dropwizard client are implementations ?  (Analogous to how like, Jakarta CDI is a spec and Quarkus ArC, Weld, etc are implementations of it)